# Mollies and Gender

Tags: fish, gender-differentiation

I got a black Molly and a dalmatian Molly on the 22nd, and today I bought another dalmatian Molly. I am a bit confused on the gender, because everything I find says something about males having a big dorsal fin and then a stick like anal fin, and the females have small dorsal fins and a seashell anal fin. So I am highly confused. Help on this?

Also, I've noticed that the bigger dal (more black) has been a little nippy towards my small one (more white) Should I be concerned about this? They're always wanting to be near each other, so I don't understand this either. The black Molly isn't very interested in either of these either, it liked my betta before I took her out. Now it just hangs by itself. [image: Dal][image: Black][image: Black][image: Dal][image: All]

Answer (score 2):

I think this images makes it very clear on how to determine better what gender your fish is:

[image]

Looking at your pictures I can see the first one as a male and the other two dalmatians as female. If you are looking for them to breed they are usually pretty easy but needs like all fishes in tank, good conditions and some hidden places depending on where you tank is (if there is movement near or nobody around ever).

Also important not to have other predators that could eat the breed.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your black molly looks like a male to me. You don't always notice fry because they are so small and transparent. I always get surprised when I see these two giant adorable eyes looking at me! Make sure to check on your tank daily and look very closely near leaves, rocks, the pebbles you have at the bottom of the tank, behind thermometers, filters, and heaters, and I've even seen mine not in the filter but resting on the side near the inside of the filter. So make sure your not missing any babies!